# Conditional Probability: Integrating out Marginal Probability

Tags: probability

For events $a,b,c$ and probability measure $p$, why does
$$
p(a|b) = \int p(a|b,c) \;p(c|b) \; dc
$$
hold? Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor).

Comment: It is just a "conditional version" of the law of total probability.

Comment: Ok, then maybe I'm confused about notation. Do we have $p([a|b]|c) = p(a|[b|c]) = p(a|b,c)$?

Comment: Or why don't we have $p(a|b) = \int p(a|b,c) \; p(c) \; dc$?

Comment: @jjjjjj We *never* have $p((a\mid b)\mid c)$ or $p(a\mid (b\mid c))$ or any such construct.  There is never more than one conditioning seperator in a probability function.  It is always $p(\text{[variable list]}\mid \text{[condition list]})$.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamKemp -- why can we not have iterated conditioning?

Comment: Because it makes no sense.  The condition divider is not a set operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
p(a)=\int p(a|c) p(c) dc \\
p(a|b) = \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} \\
p(a,b) = \int p(a,b,c) dc = \int p(a|b,c) p(b,c) dc = \int p(a|b,c) p(c|b) p(b) dc
$$
so note that $p(b)$ cancels and we are left with the statement.